# How to grep date in mm/dd/yy where dd can be any in bash?

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying the following and unable to get the desired results:

`cat sfd_log.txt | grep '12/*/17' | more`

My objective is to get all December 2017 entries from the file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` uses (optionally extended) regular expression syntax. Bash uses globbing. Similar enough to be confusing, but different enough to be important:

```
grep '12/.*/17' sfd_log.txt | more
```

Or, more precise if you like:

```
grep -E '12/[0-9][0-9]?/17' sfd_log.txt | more
```

What you actually asked for with "12/*/17" is:

> a literal '12' followed by 0 or more literal '/' followed by a literal '/17'".

Comment: #SOReadyToHelp. If it solves your problem satisfactorily, consider ticking the green checkbox to signal to future readers this worked for you.